# Inconsistent sizing of div contents after programmatic selection

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, styles

I have a tile div that is selected either by using the mouse or by a timed event. Here are the selected and unselected states :

Not .selected

[image]

.selected applied

[image]

```
.tile
{
    height: 70px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 8px auto 0px auto;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: #99b433 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile.selected
{
    border-left: 10px #2d89ef solid;
    width: 270px !important;
}
```

Problem is, this works fine when I click the tile and apply the class using css :

```
// tile click handler
$('.tile').click(function () {
    $('#leftPane').children().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

But when this is called from an ajax function after every 15 seconds :

```
$('#' + selectedId).addClass('selected');
```

I get (in chrome) :

[image]

But as soon as I hover over it, it goes back to the .selected applied pic above.

```
.tile:hover
{
    border: 2px solid #2d89ef;
}
```

Any ideas on this strange behaviour? I have tested in IE 10 and in Safari and it does not do it there.

EDIT (for eric) Here is what happens after setting auto, fills the whole width:

[image]

Comment: would you mind mocking up a jsfiddle with your html aswell so we can take a look?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/izaxuh/1/edit -- just leave it and it will make it look wrong after 5 seconds

Comment: But if you click on it, it looks different.

Comment: add margin around the parent div

Answer (score -1):

Remove `border-left` from your `.selected` class and you don't need `!important` as well:

```
.tile.selected
{
    width: 270px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/izaxuh/10/edit

Comment: what does that do besides remove his selected state?

Comment: Try and you will see [http://jsbin.com/izaxuh/10/edit](http://jsbin.com/izaxuh/10/edit)

Comment: all you are doing is removing the selected state. He wants to keep the selected state.

Comment: I'm not! Pay more attention to my answer.

Comment: Yes I want to keep that blue selection indicator.

Answer (score -1):

Its because you have `width: 270px !important;` , set the width to `auto` and it will work fine.

http://jsbin.com/izaxuh/14

Comment: There is the undesired effect of the tile now filling the entire width ... I would like spacing like it had before on each side.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I do not want it to fill the entire width.